# Detection of discontinuities of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Suppose the following functions:

**Case 1:**

$$y=f(x), x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

It can be evaluated anywhere on a specified interval $[a,b]$ and has no noise. How to detect the following discontinuities $c$ at a point $x=c$ (or
at its boundary $x\pm\varepsilon$), where $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$:

- removable discontinuities,
- jump discontinuities,
- infinite discontinuities.

In my opinion, last two discontinuities appear a straight line parallel to the $y-$ axis. I tried also to estimate the empirical error of Simpson's rule
$$
E(f,c,c+\varepsilon)=\frac{1}{15}(S(f,c,c+\varepsilon/2)+S(f,c+\varepsilon/2,c+\varepsilon)-S(f,c,c+\varepsilon)),
$$
where
$$
S(f,a,b)=\frac{b-a}{6}(f(a)+4f(c)+f(b)),\quad c=0.5(a+b),
$$
indicating the rapid increment/decrement of the area.

**Case 2:**
System of parametric functions 
\begin{align*}
x & =f(u,v),\\
y & =g(u,v),
\end{align*}
where $u\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\wedge v=v_{0}\vee u=u_{0}\wedge v\in[-\pi,\pi]$.
Here, a parametric function may pass along the singularity $c$ if:
\begin{align*}
u & \in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\wedge v_{0}=c\vee u_{0}=c\wedge v\in[-\pi,\pi]
\end{align*}
 or intersect the singularity $c$
\begin{align*}
u & =c\wedge v=v_{0}\vee u=u_{0}\wedge v=c.
\end{align*}

How to detect all three discontinuities at a point $c$ (or at its
boundary)?

Is there any computationally inefficient method working without the complex arithmetic?

Thanks for your help.